# Angular 4 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with milliseconds - how to avoid

Tags: angular

I have a view in which I want to present milliseconds which passed since last request (something like a ping). e.g.

```
Ping: {{timePassed}}
```

And I have a component with getter:

```
get timePassed() {
   return new Date().getTime() - this.lastPacket;
}
```

Obviously, when we get ***timePassed*** twice, we will get two different values (even with 1 ms difference). And because of this we'll get ***ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError***.

I'm fully aware why this error happens, but in this case I strongly insist to have this value with precision of 1 ms.

It would be really great to be able to turn off the double checking for this one particular value.

Does anybody know how to handle such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this by explicitly triggering the change,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

get timePassed() {
   this.timePassed = new Date().getTime() - this.lastPacket;
   this.cdr.detectionChanges();
}
```

Comment: Is this good approach? Any consequences/negatives of doing this?

Comment: yes indeed! Normally this is done by Angular in this case somehow runs outside Angulars zone modifies your model, then you can invoke change detection manually like

Comment: all right, but take a look at your method. You removed return from the getter which is not valid. Is it possible to call detectionChanges() before returning new value? I suppose not. I'd rather like to avoid creating additional timeouts or intervals.

Comment: ok, I've moved timePassed calculation with detectionChanges() to ngDoCheck and it works and I'm satisfied with the solution. Thanks!

Comment: This can lead to infinite loops because you have to run the change detection before the return of the getter. So after the change detection ran the getter returns its value and then the view updates and runs the getter again ...